# Cats.sequence error while applied on list of either

Tags: scala, scala-cats

I want to transform a list of `List[Either[String, Int]]` en `Either[String, List[Int]]`. For this, I want to use Cats.sequence :

```
/* for ammonite users
interp.load.ivy("org.typelevel" %% "cats-core" % "1.0.1")

@
*/

import cats.instances.list._
import cats.instances.either._
import cats.syntax.traverse._

val seqCorrect: List[Either[String, Int]] = List(Right(1), Right(2), Right(3))

val result1 = seqCorrect.sequence
```

But I have the following error :

```
Cannot prove that Either[String,Int] <:< G[A].
val result1 = seqCorrect.sequence
                         ^
```

I found the error message very unhelpful. How do I solve this problem?

Comment: that is fairly weird. It seems to work in scalafiddle
https://scalafiddle.io/sf/5J3NhLg/0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you may not have enabled `partial-unification`. The easiest way to do so, is to add the `sbt-partial-unification` [plugin](https://github.com/fiadliel/sbt-partial-unification).

If you're on Scala 2.11.9 or newer, you can also simply add the compiler flag:

```
scalacOptions += "-Ypartial-unification"
```

Comment: If you are using ammonite you can enable it with `interp.configureCompiler(_.settings.YpartialUnification.value = true)`